# Get current location from the geo fence sample project

Tags: geolocation, location, latitude-longitude, geofencing, android-geofence

I was trying out the Google's Geo fence sample project. I'm getting the entry/exit events correctly. But how can I get the current location of the user from it. I would like to keep track of user location even after entry/exit points. Please help.
The [sample project is from the developer portal.](http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need can get the user location from the Fused Location Provider in the normal fashion.  The full tutorial is here: http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

But basically, when you receive the geofence event inside your Receiver or Service, get an instance of `LocationClient` there, connect to it, and in the callback, `onConnected()`, get the last known location:

```
Location position = locationClient.getLastLocation();
```

99.9% of the time, or a little better, you'll find this location to be inside your geofence.

To continue keeping track of user location updates, follow the Receiving Location Updates: http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

Comment: Hi, just to clear my confusion does it mean that if i use geofencing, i do not have to track user locations using network or gps? Geofence does that itself?

Comment: locationClient.getLastLocation() return the current position and not one triggered the event (they are close but not the same), GeofencingEvent.getTriggeringLocation() already there without use deprecated LocationClient

Answer (score 5):

in your broadcastrecievero or service you get a GeofencingEvent , use it to get the triggering position

```
public class GeofenceTransitionsIntentService extends IntentService {

    //[...]

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
            // ...
        }

        Location l = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringLocation()

    }
    //[...]
}
```